# Are synthetic data produced by Gretel, YData, MostlyAI, etc. of higher quality than sdv-dev CTGAN?

Tags: synthetic-data

There are some online services that we can use to generate synthetic data.

On the other hand, we can also use sdv-dev CTGAN from GitHub.

Are synthetic data produced by Gretel, YData, MostlyAI, etc. of higher quality than sdv-dev CTGAN?

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/128326/115793

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "quality"?

Comment: @whuber, quality == statistically ***more*** closer to the original data.

Comment: "Statistically ... closer" has no meaning.  Please explain your sense of "close."  When you do, it would also help to indicate why it would not suffice just to reproduce the original data -- which is as close as one can possibly get in any sense of "close."

Comment: @whuber, As far as I understand, *synthetic data* is a type of *fake data* that has the same or very closely similar statistical distribution as the *example data* for which I want to generate synthetic data. Hence, for any practical purpose, that *fake data* behaves like real-world  or true data.

Comment: @whuber, Synthetic data is generated, when a use case doesn't have sufficient data points for some reason. The reason could be because of some natural phenomena, privacy concern, etc.

Comment: The problem is that "behaves like" is vague and ambiguous.  It's essential that you specify what that might mean.

Comment: @whuber, *behaves like* means: (1) it has a same or similar statistical distribution of the real-world data; (2) if we use synthetic data for, say, training an ANN model, it will give us a model that will be able to make predictions with the same/similar accuracy as if we had trained the model with actual, real-world, or true data.

Comment: +1 @whuber By and large, they compare PDFs (or similar measures), correlation matrices between multiple features, and how good a classifier trained on synthetic data performs on real-world data. (Obviously not the real-world data that were used to train the data generator) More sophisticated evaluation revolves around privacy and bias warranties. [Synthetic Data -- what, why and how?](https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.03257) by Jordon et al. is an easy-read intro on what/why. (It misses Energy-based/Diffusion models so on the *how*, I don't rate it high, but it is otherwise good.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is: *it depends*.

All papers on synthetic data analysis report the result across multiple datasets. That is because as with standard ML there is no single *best* algorithm for prediction, the same extends to data generation. For example, let's look at [TabDDPM: Modelling Tabular Data with Diffusion Models](https://arxiv.org/abs/2209.15421) by Kotelnikov et al. where they look at 15 datasets, while some methods are consistently good, no method is outright bad. (Side-comment: CTGAN is not SOTA for tabular data - diffusion model are) Our dataset characteristics make a big difference.

Synthetic data from the services mentioned have the following properties:

1. A lot of preprocessing AND post-processing done to them before we get them. That saves us time as well as gives us (some) quality assurances. (e.g. for PII information, for missing values, etc.)
2. They are (very often) generated by algorithms that have been trained not only to our query dataset, but also additional ones that have similar characteristics. That often allows them to appear more natural as well as potentially enhance their external validity.
3. Almost certainly come from a known algorithm we already have access too. Because of their size, most (all) of these companies don't have dedicated R&D departments, so they will have to methodology-wise shop from "outside", like the rest of us.

So, are the synthetic data generated by specialised data generation services better than what we could produce ourselves? *Maybe*.
In any case, if you consider using these services, I would strongly urge you to: a. have your own baselines beforehand and b. compare between different services before committing to one. As you mention yourself, running something like a simple TVAE or CTGAN to compare against what a paid service offers, is not prohibitively difficult. Similarly, based on my personal experience, synthesized data from external providers can be of vastly different "quality" levels; being able to compare between multiple ones was an eye-opener.